# React-Data-Grid set selected cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) I would like to set the currently selected cell even if the component was initialized with enabledCellSelect=false.

In [ReactDataGrid.js](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/src/addons/grids/ReactDataGrid.js) I can see that the props enableCellSelect determines whether selected is 0,0 or -1,-1.

```
getInitialState: function(): {selected: SelectedType; copied: ?{idx: number; rowIdx: number}; selectedRows: Array<Row>; expandedRows: Array<Row>; canFilter: boolean; columnFilters: any; sortDirection: ?SortType; sortColumn: ?ExcelColumn; dragged: ?DraggedType;  } {
  let columnMetrics = this.createColumnMetrics();
  let initialState = {columnMetrics, selectedRows: [], copied: null, expandedRows: [], canFilter: false, columnFilters: {}, sortDirection: null, sortColumn: null, dragged: null, scrollOffset: 0 };
  if (this.props.enableCellSelect) {
    initialState.selected = {rowIdx: 0, idx: 0};
  } else {
    initialState.selected = {rowIdx: -1, idx: -1};
  }
  return initialState;
},
```

This is fine, except in my application the data grid goes from first being unEditable and UnSelectable to selectable and editable.  And when enableCellSelect property changes from false to true, selected does not go from 0,0 to -1,-1.  Aside from modifying the library, is there any React way to setState on a mounted component?

If I did need to write a pull request, I'm thinking of using componentWillReceiveProps.  In componentWillReceiveProps I would check to see if selected was -1,-1 and enableCellSelected was true, and if so I would set selected state.

My best approach working (hopefully soon to change approach) so far was to let the component mount with enableCellSelected=true and then quickly change it to false.

Comment: I ended up writing a pull request - https://github.com/jrhicks/react-data-grid/commit/e2591a75b3e1d88a8c88b674247438961cdcb4bd

Comment: So its a bit hacky but React uses a component's "key" property to know whether to send new props into an existing component (as matched by key) or to create a new component.  Since I want a new component (since React Data Grid doesn't handle property changes well) all I needed to do was change the key when I want to EnableCellSelect